# Проблема со сменой названия окна при window.open

Tags: javascript, instagram

Помогите, пожалуйста, победить проблему. При переходе на сайт инстаграм заменяет название окна и рушится логика, что окно уже закрыто, т.к название его куда-то пропало или изменилось.

Как выявить новое название окна или в целом исправить проблему?

Полный пример:

```
<b onclick="asd()">КЛИК</b>
<script>
var NAZVANIYE_OKNA;
function asd(){
NAZVANIYE_OKNA = window.open('https://www.instagram.com/', 'Site', 'height=600,width=800,location=0, resizeable=0');
}
var interval_window = setInterval(function() {
if (NAZVANIYE_OKNA.closed){
alert("CLOOOOSEDD!");
clearInterval(interval_window);
}
}, 1010);
</script>
```

Comment: Объясните при чём тут название. Там объект типа `WindowProxy` возвращается. Поясните лучше.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Но как сделать этот пример рабочим? С другими обычными сайтами он работает отлично, а на Инстаграм ступор.

Comment: У инстаграма в ответе сервера стоит заголовок, запрещающий открывать его в попапах и фреймах ради безопасности, поэтому ничего не получается - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!